Is there a way to apply LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE to Compose Screen Level to prevent screenshots?
I have a single activity compose app and want to prevent screenshots in just a single screen. However, applying LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE to the activity window will prevent screenshots from all screens within this activity.
I know I can get the window and change it, but it must be done before setContent is called.
Are there any existing solutions? as I searched and could find nothing.
I know I can put the screen I want to prevent screenshots for in a different activity, but I would rather first see if there is a compose-friendly solution.

You need to observe the lifecycle and then set the secure flags appropriately.
This article seems good although I found that I wasn't seeing the ON_START lifecycle event so I did mine based on ON_RESUME.
I already had a lifecycle observer so I did this:
Composable
fun Lifecycle.observeAsState(): State<Lifecycle.Event> {
    val state = remember { mutableStateOf(Lifecycle.Event.ON_ANY) }
    DisposableEffect(this) {
        val observer = LifecycleEventObserver { _, event ->
            state.value = event
        }
        addObserver(observer)
        onDispose {
            removeObserver(observer)
        }
    }
    return state
}

@Composable
fun ProtectScreen() {
    val lifecycleState by LocalLifecycleOwner.current.lifecycle.observeAsState()

    val activity = LocalContext.current.getActivity()

    /* When screen has focus, set secure flag */
    when (lifecycleState) {
        Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME -> activity?.window?.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE)
        Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE -> activity?.window?.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE)
        else -> Unit
    }
    /* Also reset the flag when the composable is disposed */
    DisposableEffect(Unit) {
        onDispose { activity?.window?.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE) }
    }
}

Where (like in the article) the Context.getActivity() is a pretty standard extension method to get the activity for a given context (which can be a ContextWrapper)

I do it like this
LifecycleEventListener.kt
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.DisposableEffect
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.rememberUpdatedState
import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle
import androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleEventObserver

@Composable
fun ComponentActivity.LifecycleEventListener(event: (Lifecycle.Event) -> Unit) {
    val eventHandler by rememberUpdatedState(newValue = event)
    val lifecycle = this@LifecycleEventListener.lifecycle
    DisposableEffect(lifecycle) {
        val observer = LifecycleEventObserver { _, event ->
            eventHandler(event)
        }
        lifecycle.addObserver(observer)
        onDispose {
            lifecycle.removeObserver(observer)
        }
    }
}

ProtectedScreen.kt
import android.view.WindowManager
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.DisposableEffect
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext
import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle

@Composable
fun ProtectedScreen() {
    val activityContext = LocalContext.current as ComponentActivity
    activityContext.LifecycleEventListener(event = { lifecycleEvent ->
        when (lifecycleEvent) {
            Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME -> {
                activityContext.window?.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE)
            }
            Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE -> {
                activityContext.window?.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE)
            }
            else -> return@LifecycleEventListener
        }
    })
    DisposableEffect(Unit) {
        onDispose { activityContext.window?.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE) }
    }
}

